# Smoothness of NSProgressIndicator: incrementBy vs setDoubleValue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsprogressindicator

I suspect that [NSProgressIndicator](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSProgressIndicator_Class/Reference/Reference.html) runs smoother when its value is updated through incrementBy as compared to setDoubleValue.

Does anyone know if there's any real difference between the two methods of updating its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any knowledge of the internals, but I would be very surprised if incrementBy were not the equivalent of

```
[self setDoubleValue:[self doubleValue] + delta];
```

Of course, since it has access to internal state, it could presumably skip all the method calls.But the act of actually rendering pixels to the screen almost certainly overpowers any minor performance difference between the two methods.

Comment: im not really interested in performance difference but rather how smooth the animation of the progress bar looks to the user. I suspect you may be right but I'll leave this question open for some time to see if anyone has a more conclusive answer.

Comment: Why not just try doing both and seeing if one is more pleasant looking than the other?

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect that NSProgressIndicator runs smoother when its value is
>   updated through incrementBy as compared to setDoubleValue.

Makes no difference on macOS 10.14. When I set the `maxValue` to 1000 and then have a timer call a method every 100 ms, it looks identical, whether the method always calls `[self.progress incrementBy:1]` or `[self.progress setDoubleValue:self.step++]`, with step being an instance variable of type `NSUInteger` that is initially zero.